# Could not extract jdk-version using grep-command and regular expressions

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I am trying to extract the version of a `jdk` using `regular-expressions` Actually I have the following version:

```
openjdk 11.0.9.1 2020-11-04
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04, mixed mode,sharing)
```

I wrote the regex. It looks like the following:
`^[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}$`

**This regular expression is working on the online regex tester** (https://regex101.com/). Unfortunately, **it is not working with grep-command. I am using the extended regular expression**. My Code for the extraction of jdk-version look like the following:

```
CMD_RESULT=$(java --version 2>&1 | head -n 1 | cut -d '' -f 2)
if [ ! -z "$CMD_RESULT" ]
then 
    for token in $CMD_RESULT
    do
       JAVA_VERSION=$(echo $token |  grep -e $VERSION_EXTRACTION_REGEX)
       if [ ! -z  $JAVA_VERSION ];
       then
            printf "${GREEN}Java version: [$JAVA_VERSION]\n"
       fi
     done
fi
```

I am not understanding, why my regex is working on the online regex checker, while  it is not working with the grep-command. I am using the Parameter -e for extended regexp.

Any Idea ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have shown your attempts in your question, keep it up. Could you please post output of `java --version` command in your question with CODE TAGS for better understanding of your question.

Comment: Your regex is plain wrong; `^` matches start of line, `$` matches end of line and everything in between is restricted to digits (`[0-9]`) and dots (`\.`). Also, `grep -e` won't be enough to support this regexp, so you may have to work with extended (`grep -E`).

Comment: Could you please do mention sample of expected output for clarity in your question, which line's version you want to print, please do mention it clearly in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few small changes to OPs current code:

- as mentioned in the comments, `^` and `$` represent the beginning and ending of the input; remove these from the regex
- while `grep` can use the resulting regex it will be necessary to tell `grep` to run in `-E`xtended regex mode
- we can use `grep's` `-o` option to limit output to just the portion that matches the regex

Sample input data:

```
$ cat jdk.dat
openjdk 11.0.9.1 2020-11-04
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04, mixed mode,sharing)
```

One `grep` solution using OP's modified regex:

```
$ grep -oE '[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}' jdk.dat
11.0.9.1
11.0.9.1
11.0.9.1
```

Same thing but with the regex stored in OPs variable:

```
$ VERSION_EXTRACTION_REGEX='[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}'
$ grep -oE "${VERSION_EXTRACTION_REGEX}" jdk.dat
11.0.9.1
11.0.9.1
11.0.9.1
```

**NOTE**: I'll leave it up to the user to decide which value to use, eg, `head -n 1` to work with just the first input line (`openjdk 11.0.9.1 2020-11-04`)

Comment: Uh, I think you mean the opposite; Awk can handle (roughly) ERE syntax, while plain `grep` can't, and requires `-E` to enable support.

Comment: more like ... ***arg*** ... was jumping between a couple different answers; have updated to replace the `awk` references with `grep`; and thanks for the edit (perhaps I should step away from the keyboard for a while ...)

Answer (score 1):

Be done with using only native Bash commands to parse the java version string:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Capture java command path if it exists OR exit fail
java_cmd=$(command -v java) || exit 1

# Capture java raw version output
java_raw_version=$("$java_cmd" -version 2>&1)

# Match java raw version string against Bash Regex OR dump debug if match fail
[[ $java_raw_version =~ ([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)[_.+-]([0-9]+) ]] ||
  typeset -p java_raw_version BASH_REMATCH

major=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}   # Regex capture group 1
minor=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}   # Regex capture group 2
patch=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}   # Regex capture group 3
release=${BASH_REMATCH[4]} # Regex capture group 4

# Recompose a semantic version string
semver="$major.$minor.$patch-$release"

printf 'Java semantic version is: %s\n' "$semver"
```

Sample outputs:

From:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_275-8u275-b01-0ubuntu1~20.10-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)
```

Output:

```
Java semantic version is: 1.8.0-275
```

From:

```
openjdk 11.0.9.1 2020-11-04
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04, mixed mode,sharing)
```

Output:

```
Java semantic version is: 11.0.9-1
```

About semantic versioning, see: https://semver.org/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple `awk` solution (no need for `regexp`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Capture java command path if it exists OR exit fail
java_cmd=$(command -v java) || exit 1

# Capture java raw version output
java_raw_version=$("$java_cmd" -version 2>&1)

# print out the Java version:
echo $java_raw_version | awk -F \" 'NR==1{print "Java semantic version is: "$2}''
```

#### Explanation:

`-F \"` set awk fields separator to `"`

`NR==1` only deal with line #1

`print "Java semantic version is: "$2` append 2nd field to text and print

Comment: Getting `Java semantic version is: 1.8.0_275` which is not semantic version. And you don't need to capture a variable then echo the variable wit missing quotes. I am happy you found inspiration with my answer, but it is disappointing when not done appropriately. You would have been more innovative with `java -version 2>&1 | awk -F \" 'NR==1{split($2,ver,/[_.+-]/); printf("Semantic version: %s.%s.%s-%s\n",ver[1],ver[2],ver[3],ver[4])}'`

Comment: Why would you need to capture the path when you don't use it for anything?